# default apache page is opening instead of my webpage

Tags: virtualhost, apache2

this is my virtual host setting. whenever i trying to load my website, it will give Apache default page but after few refresh it will load my website. I tried and search about this issue but everyone is talking about virtual host config. can anyone figure out whats wrong in my virtual host config. I also disable the default virtual host config 000-default.com.conf.

```
    ServerAdmin abc@example.com
    ServerName test.example.com
    ServerAlias www.test.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/apps/staging/example
    ProxyRequests off
    <Proxy *>
            Order deny,allow
            Allow from all
    </Proxy>
    <Location />
            ProxyPass http://localhost:4204/
            ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:4204/
    </Location>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look into this folder:
`/var/www/apps/staging/example` and be sure to remove the index.html

Then you can simplify the proxypass as following:

```
ProxyPass / http://localhost:4204/
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:4204/
```